# How to setup the chat server online not local?

Tags: websocket, server, vps, ratchet

I've completed programming my site with Ratchet locally and I usually run the server file by

```
php server.php
```

now Idk how to actually make it work on the host?

I have Vps too but cant even fighre out how to connect it with the host , etc? what is the idea actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your VPS you should install a webserver for example Apache or Nginx and config them to serve requests, but actually is far more easier to use preconfigured servers with  server software management like Cpanel or directadmin that most of web hostings offer now days,
Then copy local files to remote server and adjust a database in server using a ftp client and config php web server settings, in general your webserver should point to your index.php file and thats it. You can learn other settings by exploring directadmin or Cpanel...